# What is the default scope of an entity-manager-factory Seam component?

Tags: seam

When we declare persistence units in Seam's components.xml, there's almost always a `<persistence:entity-manager-factory>` and a `<persistence:managed-persistence-context>`. Those two elements can have a `scope` attribute. What's the default scope of those two components? It's not stated in the xsd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/persistence.html#persistence.seam-managed-persistence-contexts)

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context name="bookingDatabase" 
                              auto-create="true"
               persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/EntityManagerFactories/bookingData"/>
```

> This configuration creates a conversation-scoped Seam component named bookingDatabase

and according to api of [EntityManagerFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/api/org/jboss/seam/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) this component is in application scope

```
@Scope(value=APPLICATION)
@BypassInterceptors
@Startup
```